# google map Image corrupt or truncated:

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps in popup window, at very first time the map images are not able to load properly, I checked in firebug, it shows -

```
Image corrupt or truncated: http://mt1.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=m@231000000&src=apiv3&hl=en-US&x=7&y=5&z=4&style=59,37%7Csmartmaps
```

if i close that popup window and reopen it, then map get displayed properly but when i zoom in/out it gives same above error,

is there any solution for this.

Comment: I have a similar issue, it's for "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transparent.png" and the map looks fine, but the error appears in the console.